# BLANK response for presence and online user statuses

Tags: server, xmpp

- Chat Client: ConverseJS which internally uses StropheJS
- Chat Server: Ejabberd latest version
- Chat consumed in: NodeBB Site.

To give you a background of the issue, I am doing the Connection to XMPP from server side code and passing JID, SID and RID to client, from where I use prebind / keepalive to true and connect to Chat  by passing JID, SID and RID. The connection happens successfully. However, when the chat roster loads, I do not see users ONLINE (even if they are online), No Images set (even when users have their pics set). When  I look at Fiddler to address this issue, I find the reason that the second response to XMPP which gets user details like presence, vcard information is BLANK. However, I am unable to understand the reason for having a BLANK response. Can you tell me why is it so ?

Following is the request response I captured via Fiddler:

```
POST http://ejabberd_ip/http-bind HTTP/1.1

Host: ejabberd_ip
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2184
Origin: http://community.dev.domain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
Referer: http://community.dev.domain.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

<body rid='8605' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='be3fa0fed7d04129287e665054473449d483cb66'><iq from='gmcs@domain.com/570202950143115659771440' to='conference.domain.com' type='get' xmlns='jabber:client' id='6:sendIQ'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'/></iq><iq from='gmcs@domain.com/570202950143115659771440' to='pubsub.domain.com' type='get' xmlns='jabber:client' id='7:sendIQ'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'/></iq><iq from='gmcs@domain.com/570202950143115659771440' to='vjud.domain.com' type='get' xmlns='jabber:client' id='8:sendIQ'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'/></iq><iq type='get' to='deepaktest@domain.com' xmlns='jabber:client' id='9:sendIQ'><vCard xmlns='vcard-temp'/></iq><iq type='get' to='gauri@domain.com' xmlns='jabber:client' id='10:sendIQ'><vCard xmlns='vcard-temp'/></iq><iq type='get' to='deepak@domain.com' xmlns='jabber:client' id='11:sendIQ'><vCard xmlns='vcard-temp'/></iq><iq type='get' to='adminuser@domain.com' xmlns='jabber:client' id='12:sendIQ'><vCard xmlns='vcard-temp'/></iq><iq type='get' to='stacy@domain.com' xmlns='jabber:client' id='13:sendIQ'><vCard xmlns='vcard-temp'/></iq><iq type='get' to='lynelle@domain.com' xmlns='jabber:client' id='14:sendIQ'><vCard xmlns='vcard-temp'/></iq><iq type='get' to='brian@domain.com' xmlns='jabber:client' id='15:sendIQ'><vCard xmlns='vcard-temp'/></iq><presence xmlns='jabber:client'/><iq from='gmcs@domain.com/570202950143115659771440' to='conference.domain.com' type='get' xmlns='jabber:client' id='16:sendIQ'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'/></iq><iq from='gmcs@domain.com/570202950143115659771440' to='pubsub.domain.com' type='get' xmlns='jabber:client' id='17:sendIQ'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'/></iq><iq from='gmcs@domain.com/570202950143115659771440' to='vjud.domain.com' type='get' xmlns='jabber:client' id='18:sendIQ'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'/></iq></body>


RESPONSE FOR 2nd request is BLANK : 
===================================
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Thu, 07 May 2015 16:21:06 GMT
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 51
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type

<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'/>
```